# Learning how to HTML and how to optimize my page

Tags: html

I'm using a website to help me to found speed issues on my website.

This problem occurred but I don't know how to solve this

> **Specify a character set early** The following resources have no character set specified in their HTTP headers. Specifying a character
>   set in HTTP headers can speed up browser rendering.

My code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name=description content="EFR3SXZ's personal site">
<meta property=og:title content=EFR3SXZ>
<meta property=og:description content="EFR3SXZ's personal site">
<meta property=og:image content=http://richpreview.com/richpreview.png>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href=http://richpreview.com/favicon.ico type=image/x-icon>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Dead Centre</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        <!-- body {
            color: white;
            background-color: #003;
            margin: 0px
        }

        #horizon {
            color: white;
            background-color: transparent;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
            overflow: visible;
            visibility: visible;
            display: block
        }

        #content {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: transparent;
            margin-left: -125px;
            position: absolute;
            top: -35px;
            left: 50%;
            width: 250px;
            height: 70px;
            visibility: visible
        }

        .bodytext {
            font-size: 14px
        }

        .headline {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 24px
        }

        #footer {
            font-size: 11px;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
            visibility: visible;
            display: block
        }

        a:link,
        a:visited {
            color: #06f;
            text-decoration: none
        }

        a:hover {
            color: red;
            text-decoration: none
        }

        -->
    </style>
    <title>EFR3SXZ</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="horizon">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="bodytext">
                Incarnoob
                <br>
                <span class="headline">EFR3SXZ</span>
                <br>website</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <a href="http://www.dofus.com/pt/mmorpg/comunidade/anuarios/paginas-personagens/727072906001-incarnoob">Incarnoob's Dofus page</a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As an aside, you should also move your `<meta>` tags into your `<head>` tag. You also have two `<title>` tags on this page, meaning one will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML you use is largely irrelevant to the HTTP headers. How you set those depends on the HTTP server you are using and (if applicable) the server side programming language that is generating the response.

If you were (for example) using Apache HTTPD, you might edit your server configuration file to include:

```
AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
```

(NB: I'd suggest moving away from legacy encodings and use UTF-8 now it is the 21st century).

Comment: Im using .htaccess, what should I do?

Comment: `AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1`